# Raspberry Piにボタンを5個以上設定する方法

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

[こちらのサイト](http://lchikaamazon.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/11/18/171637)を参考にボタンでRaspberry Piに命令を送ることが出来るようになったのですが、ボタンひとつに付き、電源とGPIOとGroundが必要になるようでボタンを5つ作りたいのに電源が4つしか見つからず困っています。

何か方法があるとは思うのですが、このような場合どう対処するもなのでしょうか？
恥ずかしながら電子工作の知識は全くといっていいほどない状態です。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ブレッドボードを使う場合の例ですが、こんな感じに配線すれば電源をたくさん引き出す必要はありません。

- 青: GPIO
- 赤: 3.3V
- 黒: Ground
  (図では赤を2ピンに接続してありますが、1ピン/3.3Vに接続してください)

[image: 回路]

Comment: 図付きの詳しい解説ありがとうございます。教えていただいた配線で複数のボタンが正常に動いてるのを確認できました。